# How many disk seeks does it take to write one row on SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, csv

As far as I understand, there can be one disk-seek per rotation of a harddisk, therefore I am interested to know how many disk seeks are needed for writing a row to an SQLite table, including locking etc. Assume that there are no indexes on the table (not even a primary key). I assume that there is one disk seek to write a line to a file? As you understand, I want to compare performance with writing the same data to a flat file.

Comment: How will you compare performance? How does knowing how many seeks are involved help you compare performance?

Comment: @jcolebrand, I am assuming that disk seeks will be the biggest performance bottleneck when writing a row to a table. Am I wrong about this assumption?

Comment: You might be. It all depends on what you're measuring. This is the science part of computer science.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was answered on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242653/how-many-disk-seeks-does-it-take-to-write-one-row-to-a-sqlite-database/6242688#6242688).

> By default its one transaction per
>   disk rotation (roughly),
>
> http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19
>
> The way to speedier writes is to wrap
>   multiple ones inside a transaction.